# Do we really need these tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I was looking around the tag section and two of them caught my attention.
[growling](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/growling) and [purring](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purring) I was wondering why do we have these too specific(IMHO) tags, if anything both should just fall under [behavior](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior) no?

Comment: Not entirely convinced, though I'm inclined to agree with you in general. I'll wait to see if any other weigh in before I start tag synonyms though.

Comment: Well not really asking for a deletion or anything in particular @JohnCavan I'm just trying to discuss if we really need them, based on the outcome/feedback of this question we can then proceed to make a request or simply move on

Comment: That was the gist of my comment... I wanted to note that I generally agree with the premise though. Nevertheless, for the discussion to have a point, there's probably some form of action to arise, no?

Comment: True, @JohnCavan

Comment: Related [Should we work on creating tag synonyms?](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2094)

Comment: Done, don't hesitate to post more if you get another good idea.

Answer (score 4):

We could also consider connecting [growling](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/growling) and [purring](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purring) to [vocalizations](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocalizations). [behavior](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior) is pretty broad IMO.

I could honestly see either one, so thought I'd post this as an answer to allow the community to decide by votes.

Comment: This answer received great support, the merge and synonym creation has been completed.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of making [growling](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/growling) and [purring](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purring) synonyms  of [behavior](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior). As synonyms they will still exist but will convert to [behavior](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior) when used.